# Merge items of a List basing on condition

Tags: java

I have a List of a custom object :

```
public class CustomObject {

    protected String field1;
    protected String field2;
    protected String field3;
    protected List<String> listOfString;
} 

List<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
CustomObject customObject1 = new CustomObject("1234", "", "", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
CustomObject customObject2 = new CustomObject("1234", "", "notblank", Arrays.asList("c", "d"));

CustomObject customObject3 = new CustomObject("", "1234", "", Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
CustomObject customObject4 = new CustomObject("", "1234", "notblank", Arrays.asList("c", "d"));

list.add(customObject1);
list.add(customObject2);
list.add(customObject3);
list.add(customObject4);
```

I would like to apply a custom method to merge two items of the list, comparing each items.
For example, iterating over the list, if customObject1.getField1() equals
customObject2.getField1(), i want to apply my merge function.

In my example, customObject1 should be merged with customObject2, and customObject3 should be merged with customObject4 because its have same field1 or same field2.

By the way, my merge function consists to add "listOfString" of the customObject which have a blank "field3" to the one with the filled "field3".`

My merge function is to keep listOfString in the custom object which has a blank field3.  This listOfString will be added into the listOfString of the other custom object, the one which will be merged in one. For example if cutomObject1 and customObject2 are merged in one, we should have this :

```
public class CustomObject {

    protected String field1; = "1234"
    protected String field2; = ""
    protected String field3; = "notblank"
    protected List<String> listOfString; = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

I succeed in doing it using Collectors.toMap() which works, but when i only compare field1 :

```
Map<List<String>, CustomObject> map = myList.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(customObject -> customObject.getField1(),
                        individu -> individu, this::customMergeMethod));
```

But my problem is : i want to merge items if customObject1.getField1() equals
customObject2.getField1() **OR** if customObject1.getField2() equals
customObject2.getField2(). And I think is not possible to use Collectors.toMap() in this case.

What should i use to fix this ? Thank you

I tried using a Set with a overrided compare method, but how to use my custom merge method with this, if it is possible ?

```
Set<CustomObject> s = new TreeSet<CustomObject>(new Comparator<CustomObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(CustomObject customObject1, CustomObject customObject2) {
        [...]
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include an example list of several `CustomObject` instances and write the resulting List/Collection/Set/Map/container you want based on the example list. It is unclear how you want to "merge" your data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **exact** result you want from your merge as example java code. But before that, add example input objects with non-empty strings to show, how these values are "merged".

Comment: Seems the only way to use `Set` and (stream.collect...collision) "merge" function is to override (Object) equals+hashCode (with the mentioned conditions)... alternatively: use "custom loop" ...with custom compare/equals function and any "container" (set/list/array...) you like

Comment: `By the way, my merge function consists to add "listOfString" of the customObject which have a blank "field3" to the one with the filled "field3"`. I did not catch it, could you add an example for it? Looks like you use composite key, what would be if `customObject2`  will have `field2 = "1234"`. Shall we merge 1,2,3, 4 object to one in this case?

Comment: if customObject2 have field2 = "1234", yes in this case all the custom objects should be merged to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like yet another question on "how can I achieve XYZ using streams, despite using plain loop would be way easier"

---

However you could introduce a new `CustomKey` class (I'm using a record to get equals/hashCode) to hold the composite keys of your `CustomObject` for use in `Collectors.toMap`:

```java
public record CustomKey(String field1, String field2) {};

Map<CustomKey, CustomObject> map = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              o -> new CustomKey(o.field1, o.field2),
              Function.identity(),
              this::customMergeMethod)
         );
```

If you have other/additional/more complex requirements regarding when to merge two items, override hashCode/equals for `CustomKey` and implement these requirements in these methods.

---

*UPDATE*:
Given the snippet in the comments, the `CustomKey` class could look like this:

```java
public class CustomKey {
    String field1; String field2;
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (!obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final CustomKey otherKey = (CustomKey)obj;
        
        final String thisKeyValue = StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(this.field1, StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(this.field2, ""));
        final String otherKeyValue = StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(otherKey.field1, StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(otherKey.field2, ""));
        
        return Objects.equals(thisKeyValue, otherKeyValue);
    }
};
```

You should notice that with this implementation you will compare `field1` values with `field2` values, if `this` has a non-blank `field1` and `obj` only has `field2`. However this matches you snippet from the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you said but unfortunatelly i'm unable to override my "equals" method from my class CustomKey (i created a class insted of a record beauce i only have JDK8). Instead of merging, it doesn't merge ... 
However i tried to create a custom method instead of a class, which return what i want to detect if field1 or field2 are the same, and it seems to work ... do you know the differences between create a class or a method ?

Comment: Please add some updates to your question. It's kind of hard to figure out what you're asking for.

Comment: This is what i did :

```
Map<String, CustomObject> map = myList.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(this::getCustomKey,
                        customObject -> customObject, this::customMergeMethod));

private String getCustomKey(final CustomObject customObject) {

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(individu.getFiled1())) {
            return individu.getField1();
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(individu.getField2())) {
            return individu.getField2();
        }

        return "";
    }

```
Sorry for the wrong block code :(

Comment: Basically the merge function is called whenever `key1.equals(key2)`. My guess would be that you have some error in the `CustomKey.equals` method. I updated the question with an equals implementation that should match your snippet.

Comment: It works properly, very clean code thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: I just had to override the method hashCode() too, in my class CustomKey to make the overriden method equals() works. Otherwise the topMap() method was considering the one of Object class.

Comment: Yes, equals and hashCode always come together...